# Upload Code on Arduino Mega using FTDI Cable

Tags: arduino-mega, ftdi

I would like to upload my code to the Arduino Mega 2560.

1. The USB is fried hence I have to use the FTDI
2. I've a FTDI cable, but it has only 4 wires, Vcc,GND,TX,RX

How do you upload, as the ATmega is not responding to anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTDI cables usually have RTS which is used to bring `Reset` low. If you only have four pins, press the Reset button on the board the moment you start the upload.

Comment: Thanks, But this need a bit of luck

Comment: \*shrug\* - well get an FTDI cable with the extra wire then.

Comment: Such a simple answer Nick, but works like a charm. I was on the verge of chucking the damn thing out the window, thank you.